# how to set value of octal in java?

Tags: java, octal

I am trying to write following code.but it gives me error kindly help me.

```
    int six=06;
    int seven=07;
    int abc=018;
    int nine=011;
    System.out.println("Octal 011 ="+nine);
    System.out.println("octal O18 =" + abc);
```

why i cant give 018 and 019 to variable.i can give value 020 and 021 to variable.
Why this happen? what's the reason behind this Kindly tell me.
I got Following error

```
            integer number too large: 018
            int eight=018;
```

Comment: octal Number consist only 0 to 7. and you are breaking that restriction.

Comment: What result did you *expect* for `abc`? It feels like you haven't really understood what octal is about...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Octal is base-8 number system, so it means digit can be from 0 to 7, you can't use digit 8 (and 9 too) in octal number system.

Comment: It is very interesting to note that a rather commonly looking code `int a = 019` will NOT compile, and another code that looks entirely harmless, `int b = 010`, yields a completely different result than one not familiar with octal notation, may expect! Just something to keep in mind...

Answer (score 32):

```
// Decimal declaration and possible chars are [0-9]
int decimal    =  495;        

// HexaDecimal declaration starts with 0X or 0x and possible chars are [0-9A-Fa-f]
int hexa       =  0X1EF; 

// Octal declaration starts with 0 and possible chars are [0-7] 
int octal      =  0757;  

// Binary representation starts with 0B or 0b and possible chars are [0-1]  
int binary     =  0b111101111;
```

If the number is string format then you can convert it into int using the below

```
String text = "0b111101111";
int value = text.toLowerCase().startsWith("0b") ? Integer.parseInt(text.substring(2), 2)
                                  : Integer.decode(text);
```

Comment: Integer.decode() does not parse binary ("0b1010...") - it parses only hex,octal and decimal.

Answer (score 26):

> why i cant give 018 and 019 to variable.

Because an integer literal prefixed with `0` is treated as octal, and '8' and '9' aren't valid octal digits.

From [section 3.10.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Trying to use '8' in an octal number is like trying to use 'G' in hex... it's simple not part of the set of symbols used in that base.

Answer (score 8):

Octal numbers (base 8) can only use the following figures: `01234567`. The same way that decimal numbers (base 10) can only use `0123456789`.

So in octal representation, `17 + 1` is `20`.

Comment: @miliu you are mixing octal and decimal - I meant: 017 + 01 = 020.

Answer (score 7):

> why i cant give 018 and 019 to variable.i can give value 020 and 021 to variable.

The leading zero signifies an octal literal. However, `8` and `9` are not valid octal digits. This makes `018` and `019` invalid.

Answer (score 7):

The prefix 0 indicates octal(8 base)(digits 0-7).

```
public class MainClass{

  public static void main(String[] argv){

    int intValue = 034;  // 28 in decimal
    int six = 06; // Equal to decimal 6
    int seven = 07; // Equal to decimal 7
    int eight = 010; // Equal to decimal 8
    int nine = 011; // Equal to decimal 9

    System.out.println("Octal 010 = " + eight);

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I forget about for the prefix and I was looking for it :)

Answer (score 5):

When an integer literal starts with 0 in Java, it's assumed to be in octal notation. The digits `8` and `9` are illegal in octal—the digits can range only between 0 and 7.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's octal, an octal number has `8` digits which spans from `0` to `7` inclusive. For the same reason `12` would be an invalid binary number.

You need at least base `9` to have `18` and a normal decimal base for `19`.

Answer (score -1):

For your query.....you assign an invalid value to the variable....your assigned value is started with 0(zero) ..which means that you are assigning an octal value to the variable and when you assign a value higher then 7 such as 018 in your case...the value excedes the range of octal variables and hence show an error...so try entering simply 18 so it would take it as an integer rather than an octal variable data type...