# Padded zeroes as a part of an input for a data structure

Tags: java

So I created a custom linkedlist and while testing it to ensure functionality, I noticed something weird.

When I run this code:

```
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty());
    
    list.add(13);
    list.add(423);
    list.add(23);
    list.add(022);
    list.add(122);
    list.add(25);
    
    System.out.println(list.get(1));
    
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty());
    
    for (Integer i: list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

I get this output:

true
423
false
13
423
23
18
122
25

Why is it that 022 got converted into 18?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why int j = 012 giving output 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039871/why-int-j-012-giving-output-10)

Answer (score 2):

Because it's taken as an octal base (8) since that numeral has 0 in leading. So, it's corresponding decimal value is 18.

**022**

```
= (2 * 8 ^ 0) + (2 * 8 ^ 1)
= (2 * 1) + (2 * 8)
=  2 + 16
=  18
```

Comment: why octal? is it because 2 was the highest integer value?

Comment: Because an integer literal prefixed with 0 is treated as octal.