# "The literal 0008 of type int is out of range"

Tags: java, int

I have what is probably a Java 101 question.  I am creating objects which take an int in the constructor.  Don't ask why, but I decided to enter "0001" and then "0002" and then "0003" and so on when manually creating objects.  In the end, I created twelve:  0001 through 0012.

Here's the weird thing...  on 0008 (and 0009), I got this error:  "*The literal 0008 of type int is out of range.*"  No problem with 0001 through 0007, nor 0010 through 1012.  Just problems with 0008 and 0009.

Its not a big deal to rewrite my code to use "1", "2", "3", ... "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" but I'd like to understand this error.  Any ideas?

Many thanks! 
-P

Comment: When starting a number with 0, it means you are using octal notation. More details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433781/how-to-set-value-of-octal-in-java

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: octal supports from only 0-7

Comment: Thanks - I've never heard of octal notation...  that gives me something to read up on.  Much appreciated!