# Cast from float to double

Tags: java, casting, compilation, boolean, expression

Can someone please explain me why this code doesn‘t compile:

```
boolean r = (boolean) 0;
```

Why does this one compile?

```
double z = (float) 2.0_0+0___2;
```

I don‘t understand the Alphabet in which the numbers after float are written.

Comment: For the second part, see this page : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

Comment: 1: There is no cast from an int to a boolean in Java. 2: Underscores are ignored inside number literals.

Comment: Be careful with numbers which begin with a `0` since java handle these as a octal number. For example: `int i = 010;System.out.println(i);` will print `8`.

Answer (score 9):

The first one doesn't compile because you simply can't cast a number to a `boolean`. A `boolean` is `true` or `false`.

The second one just uses underscores, which [can be used to separate numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) like `2_000_000` for improved readability. In this case they're used to decrease readability, as is the cast to `float` (a `double` cast to `float` and assigned to `double` doesn't do anything in this particular case).

The latter case seems to be designed for confusion, as there are several pitfalls. If we remove the unnecessary underscores we get `2.00+02` which adds a literal `double` with an [octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433781/how-to-set-value-of-octal-in-java) `02`. This is still basically just `2+2`, but if the octal value were `0___10` you'd get a result of `z = 10`. Then you have the cast to `float` which could affect the final result, as 64 bits are forced to 32 bits and then back to 64 bits. This could make the end result less precise than without the cast.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages, like PHP or Javascript 0 is falsy, that is, not `false`, but evaluated as a `boolean` value, it will be `false`. In C, 0 is `false`. These are possible reasons for your expectation. However, in Java you cannot convert a number to a `boolean`. If you want to have a truey-ish evaluation, you can implement helper methods, like:

```
public class LooselyTyped {
    public boolean toBoolean(int input) {
        return input != 0;
    }

    public boolean toBoolean(Object input) {
        return (input != null) && (!input.equals(""));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
boolean lt = LooselyTyped.toBoolean(yourvariable);
```