# How do i compare variables containing integers

Tags: java

```
package Tutorial;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tutorial {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   String name="revolt";
   int password=0123;
   String Name;
   int Password;
   System.out.println("enter name;");
   Name=sc.nextLine();
   if (Name.equals(name)){
   System.out.println("enter password");
   }
   else{
     System.out.println("wrong Name");
   }
   Password=sc.nextInt();
   if (password==Password){
     System.out.println("access granted...");
   }
   else{
     System.out.println("wrong 
Password!");
   }
  }
}
```

The code doesn't show any error but when I enter password it tells me wrong password even though the password is correct.

Comment: Without going into much detail about your code, do you know that the number `0123`is the octal number corresponding to `83`decimal, right?

Comment: Please, please don't use variables with the same name ever. This is a very bad practice and you shouldn't start with that. Rather give your variables descriptive names - so instead of Password, you would take passwordInput or something like that.

Comment: No I didn't so what should i do now

Comment: @EdithStark Well, the obvious deduction is that the password is 83, not 123 or 0123. I believe that's probably your problem, right?

Comment: Why are you using an int for your password? Given that ints cannot start with 0, you should use a `String` instead. Make sure you remember to use `str.equals()` to compare strings.

Comment: Alright it worked.

Comment: But why use 83 instead of the specified 0123,expanciate please.

Comment: @EdithStark it is explained in my first comment. A literal integer that starts with prefix `0` is interpreted by Java as an octal number (e.g. 0123), just as any number starting with `0x` is an hexadecimal and with `0b`is binary. But when you provide your integer from the command line you proviate a base-10 number.

Comment: @EdithStark You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433781/how-to-set-value-of-octal-in-java

Comment: Okay I now understand

Answer (score 1):

You now know what the issue is but, if you are determined to force a User to provide a numerical password (regardless of the order of digits) then make password a String variable and utilize the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method to get User input. Once you have that input, check it using the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) to ensure that only numerical digits were supplied, for example:

```
/* User must enter an all numerical password that is a 
   minimum of 4 digits to a maximum of 18 digits.  */  
String password = "";
while(password.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter your numerical Password: --> ");
    System.out.print  ("(enter 'q' to quit): --> ");
    password = sc.nextLine().trim();
    if (password.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
        System.out.println("Quitting ... Bye-Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // Password must be all numerical, 
    // be a minimum of 4 digits in length, 
    // and be a maximum of 18 digits in length.
    if (!password.matches("\\d+") || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 18) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Password Supplied (" + password + ")!\n"
                + "A password must contain a 'minimum' of at least four (4)\n"
                + "all numerical digits to a 'maximum' of 18 digits! No alpha\n"
                + "characters or whitespaces are allowed!");
        password = "";
    }
}
```

The Regular Expression `\\d+` within the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method checks to make sure that what is now within the **password** string variable is indeed a string representation of one or more numerical digits from 0 to 9. A password of `0123` would be considered valid however if you were to parse this to Integer or Long for example, the `0` is omitted.